# Is the selection of ARMA(0,0) wrong?

Tags: arma

From my model selection based on information criteria such as SBIC returns me a ARMA(0,0) model. Should I choose it or reject it? and Why?

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: This is impossible to answer as is. Please provide a *lot* more context. What are your variables? What models were tested with SBIC? What did autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation look like? How much serial correlation is there? A plot of the variable would also help.

Comment: (1) Why did you include an ARMA(0,0) model in the set of candidate models in the first place? It hasn't got _less_ plausible through having the lowest information criterion value of the lot. (2) Is there any reason to worry that _none_ of the candidate models is much good? - are there signs of assumption violations or more complex structure than allowed for in any?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your data is "white noise", so the information criterion suggests you an ARMA(0,0) model.

For example in R:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(123)
d<-rnorm(1000)
auto.arima(d)
```

gives you an ARMA(0,0) model. So there seems to be no structure in your data which can be exploited in the context of an ARMA model.

Comment: It is true that white noise will yield a ARMA(0,0) model, but it is not necessarily true that all ARMA(0,0) models are white noise. There could be something else going on, not captured by the model. Or N could be low. Or there could be a lot of noise on top of something actual.